# Need help in solving an unbalanced recursion tree problem

Tags: recursion, tree, time-complexity

I am trying to solve an unbalanced recursion tree problem. 
Here is the question:

T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/5) + n^3

I tried drawing the tree, but I am stuck on solving the problem. Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that  order of this recursion  is at least n^3 because any step use n^3. And also we know that T(n)<= 2T(2n/5)+n^3 and solution of this recursion by master theorem is o(n^3). and finally we conclude that  T(n)=theta(n^3)

Comment: Thanks. I have done it. I got the same answer. O(n^3).